# C Conditional Statement

Tags: c

I came across the following piece of code.

```
int main()
{
  int i=1,j=2;
  int a=i--?printf("%d",i):j--;
  printf(" %d %d %d",i,j, a);
  return 0;
}
```

The output is 0 0 2 1.

I understand the rest of the output except the first 0.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Its altered from 1 to 0 by `i--`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `0` is the value of `i`, which was initialized as `1` then decremented in the second line.

More explicitly:

```
i = 1
(i--) - evaluates as True, then sets i to 0
printf("%d ", i) = prints '0'
j--   - skipped
printf("%d %d %d", i, j, a)
print i: 0
print j: 2 (unchanged)
print a: return value of first `printf` : character count (1)
```

As @tristopia pointed out in a comment, there are two closely related concepts in play here:

1. Post-fix operators: the value that is used in the expression is the value *before* increment takes place...
2. Sequence point: a point in the code where "all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed" - in other word, "everything that needs to have happened will happen before we pass this point". For example, any variable that was post-fix incremented is guaranteed to be incremented (and stored) when you pass the sequence point.

The key here is that the `?` of the ternary operator is such a sequence point - thus you are sure that `i` will have been decremented before you get to the `printf` statement.

Contrast this with code like:

```
i = 1;
a = 5 * i++ + (i = 2 * i--);
```

This leads to undefined behavior - there is nothing in the C standard that can tell you definitively what the value of `a` or `i` will be after the above. When should the value of `i++` be stored back in `i`? Before the decrement operation? How about the fact that we are assigning a result to `i`? Does that come before, or after, the other "implicit store" operations? Most compilers will warn you when they come across such a line - if you have a specific order of operations in mind you should "force sequence points" by rewriting the code.

Comment: I understand that i gets decremented. But as they have used a postfix operator, i was confused. So if I am right, the statement is evaluated, then i is decremented and then is printed.?

Comment: Even if that piece of code is ugly, I dont see anything here that leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - you are right, I looked more closely. Updated accordingly.

Comment: One should at least mention the concept of **sequence point**. The ternary operator has one between the boolean expression and result value. That is the reason why OP's expression is not "undefined behaviour".

Comment: @tristopia - great point. I have modified my answer to take this into account.

Answer (score 2):

The value of i doesn't decrement before the condition check is done on it (due to postfix decrement). The test evaluates to true as i is 1, resulting in printf getting executed. But just as the test of i is over, it gets decremented, which is what printf prints on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're calling `printf()` twice. The first one in the conditional operator prints the value of `i` (0). When you created the variable `a` it had a default value of 0, and `i` became 0 after decrementing it with `i--`, so the condition passed.

Then you have your second `printf()` which prints `i` again along with the other 2 values.